# How can I collect an istream_view into a container?

Tags: c++, containers, c++20, std-ranges, istream-view

I was trying to implement a generic reduction operation for my extensions for [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20)'s `ranges` that would collect the elements of any `range` into a given container. To achieve that, I first created a dummy type for extracting a `template template` parameter and provided `operator|` for combing a `range` with it:

```
template <template <typename> typename T>
struct to_fn { };

template <template <typename> typename T>
inline constexpr detail::functors::to_fn<T> to;

template <template <typename> typename T>
auto operator|(std::ranges::range auto&& rng, detail::functors::to_fn<T>) {
    return T(std::ranges::begin(rng), std::ranges::end(rng));
}
```

Tested as follows:

```
int main() {
    using namespace std::ranges;
    std::vector<int> vec = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    auto set = vec | to<std::set>;
    static_assert(std::same_as<decltype(set), std::set<int>>);
    assert(equal(vec, set));
}
```

the code finished execution with no problem.

However, the code fails to compile when used with `std::ranges::istream_view`:

```
int main() {
    using namespace std::ranges;
    std::ifstream input_file("input.txt");
    auto vec = istream_view<int>(input_file) | to<std::vector>;
}
```

This **fails** to compile with a wall of errors, among which, in my opinion, the important one being:

> ```
> note:   deduced conflicting types for parameter '_InputIterator' ('std::ranges::basic_istream_view<int, char, std::char_traits<char> >::_Iterator' and 'std::default_sentinel_t')
> 122 |   return T(std::ranges::begin(rng), std::ranges::end(rng));
>     |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> ```

This makes sense to me. Containers require that the iterators used to construct them via constructors taking two of them are *of the same type*.

But that's fine - that's what `std::ranges::views::common_view` was created for. So I tried to modifying `operator|` to:

```
template <template <typename> typename T>
auto operator|(std::ranges::range auto&& rng, detail::functors::to_fn<T>) {
    auto common = rng | std::ranges::views::common;
    return T(std::ranges::begin(common), std::ranges::end(common));
}
```

Which, again, **failed** to compile with a smaller wall of errors, among which I believe this one is the most relevant:

> ```
> note: the expression 'is_constructible_v<_Tp, _Args ...> [with _Tp = std::ranges::basic_istream_view<int, char, std::char_traits<char> >::_Iterator<int, char, std::char_traits<char> >; _Args = {std::ranges::basic_istream_view<int, char, std::char_traits<char> >::_Iterator<int, char, std::char_traits<char> >&}]' evaluated to 'false'
> 139 |       = destructible<_Tp> && is_constructible_v<_Tp, _Args...>;
>     |                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> ```

I don't quite get what this error indicates, but I suppose this means that `istream_view` cannot be copy-constructed. Kind of makes sense to me.

---

But I really wish I could have this generic `to` "functor". I figured that it's okay to loop over `istream_view` with *range-based `for`* and add elements to the chosen container, when we deduce that we are dealing with an *input range*<sup>1</sup>.

So I tried this:

```
template <template <typename> typename T>
auto operator|(std::ranges::range auto&& rng, detail::functors::to_fn<T>) {
    using namespace std::ranges;
    using range_t = decltype(rng);
    const bool input_range = std::is_same_v<
            iterator_t<range_t>::iterator_category,
            std::input_iterator_tag>;
    if constexpr(input_range) {
        auto container = T<range_value_t<range_t>>();
        for (auto&& element : rng) {
            container.generic_add(element); // ???
        }
        return container;
    } else {
        auto common = rng | views::common;
        return T(begin(common), end(common));
    }
}
```

Which then told me, among other things, that:

> ```
> error: 'iterator_category' is not a member of 'std::ranges::iterator_t<std::ranges::basic_istream_view<int, char, std::char_traits<char> >&&>'
> 125 |             iterator_t<range_t>::iterator_category,
>     |                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> ```

This is not the only problem. There is also a problem of generically adding elements to any container. The constructor taking a `range` is, to my knowledge, the only generic way and *good* way of adding elements to the container.

I feel like there must be a correct and simpler way of doing what I am trying to do. Bonus points if `to` also works for non-templates, i.e., I could not only do `to<std::vector>` but also `to<std::string>`. In the first case, it would deduce the elements and create the desired instantiation of `std::vector`, but in the second case it would take all elements and initialise an `std::string` with those. How can I make this work?

---

<sup>1</sup> This assumes that the actual problem lies in the fact that we are using *input range*. I am not sure whether that's the case. I would love if someone could point out the possible error in my reasoning.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For [c++23](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b23), `ranges::to` ([P1206R7](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p1206r7.pdf)) will correctly handle move-only views.

---

> This assumes that the actual problem lies in the fact that we are using *input range*.

The problem isn't that it's an input range, the problem is that `std::ranges::istream_view<int>`, along with its iterator type, are move-only.

In C++17, all iterators had to be copyable. That restriction was relaxed in C++20, we can now have move-only iterators and move-only views. But code has to change to support that - `std::vector`'s iterator-pair constructor is still based on the C++17 iterator model, which does copy iterators around, so it cannot work for `std::ranges::istream_view<int>::iterator`.

The point of `common_view` is to take a C++20 range, one that has a sentinel type that differs from its iterator type, and adapt it to work with C++17 algorithms by producing the same type for both the iterator and sentinel. But the point here is to work with C++17 algorithms, and so it has to adhere to C++17 iterator requirements. Those requirements include copyability, so `common_view` is declared as, from [[range.common.view]](http://eel.is/c++draft/range.common.view):

```cpp
namespace std::ranges {
  template<view V>
    requires (!common_range<V> && copyable<iterator_t<V>>)
  class common_view : public view_interface<common_view<V>> {
```

That's why `rng | views::common` doesn't compile for you, `common` requires copyability (in the case where the iterator/sentinel type differ, as they do here) and you don't have that (also you should be forwarding `rng`, since even if `views::common` didn't require copyability directly, what you're doing is actually copying it, so would fail separately).

There's really no way to adapt `std::ranges::istream_view<int>` such that you can use `vector<int>`'s iterator-pair constructor. We would need to either change `vector` in some way to allow this construction to work (which certainly doesn't help you right now), or you have to handle this case by doing the equivalent of:

```cpp
std::vector<int> v;
for (int e : rng) {
    v.push_back(e);
}
return v;
```

Though that has to look like `s.insert(e)` for the `std::set` case.

Comment: Great explanation, thank you. So there is no real way of implementing `to` than to manually SFINAE on insetion method, correct?

Comment: @Fureeish Basically, yeah.

Comment: @Barry Why do we have to deprive the copyability of `std::ranges::istream_view::iterator`, while `std::istream_iterator` is copyable, and their method of implementation are almost the same?

Comment: @xxhxx Well, `std::istream_iterator` isn't _really_ copyable anyway, since you can't use both the copy and the original. Doing so is an error. So making the new version _not_ copyable more accurately expresses how the usability of the type. Which, I would think, is a good thing.